# User In Unreal Engine 5, HDRI leaves shadows on a layer for an object that is not present on that layer. How can these shadows be removed?

Tags: unreal-engine5

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckJeR.jpg)
All changes with static/dynamic shadows 0 reaction.

I'am using composure sompositing. Another types of lighting works well in same situation, broblem just when using hdri or just skylight with hdri cubemap.

I tried change global illumination setting. Tried change shadows settings.